# ProgrammingError at / relation "website_request" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "website_request"

Tags: python, django, heroku

this is my first deployment to heroku and i am getting the above error, i did everything right, I mean I think so at least and still getting the error. am deploying via  heroku CLI

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're asking us to guess what you have written. We know nothing about the code except that you think it's correct. How can we tell you how to fix it? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: I assume as a professional you might have a good guess on what went wrong. I just wrote the error above and i have no idea where it comes from

Comment: If you want help, please provide us with the information that the SO guidelines tell you to provide.  Why should we have to guess? To make it all more of a challenge?

Comment: Have you applied your database migrations on Heroku? Are you using a framework like Django or Flask / Alembic?

Comment: @Dullah, please read [ask]. BoarGules is correct that there isn't very much information here. "I assume as a professional you might have a good guess on what went wrong" isn't a very helpful response.

Comment: @Chris yes i am using Django, when I apply the migrations at heroku i also get some errors

Comment: Okay. What are the errors? "Some errors" doesn't tell us very much. Have you read the [ask] page that both BoarGules and I have asked you to read?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of regular text. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)